# create cookie won't work

Tags: javascript, cookies

I absolutely cannot figure out what is wrong with this code,

This first iteration works perfectly:

```
if (window.location.href != "http://fiddlehead.co/pages/verify-age") {
current_url = window.location;
document.cookie = 'landing_Cookie=' + escape(current_url) +';'
};
```

But I need the cookie to expire in a matter of seconds and this isn't working(no cookie is created):

```
if (window.location.href != "http://fiddlehead.co/pages/verify-age") {
function createCookie(name, value) {
   var date = new Date();
   date.setTime(date.getTime()+(30*1000));
   var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
   var current_url = window.location;
   document.cookie = name+"="+escape(value)+expires+"; path=/";
 };
 createCookie('landing_Cookie', current_url);
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is the last hurdle of many hours of banging my head against the table!

Comment: Do you test on a server or by opening the file on local filesystem?

Comment: I don't, I'm testing by making changes on a live server.

Comment: `document.cookie = name+"="+escape(value)+expires+"; path=/";` Is the syntax on this line correct or is the path syntax wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var current_url = window.location;` must be placed out of the body of `createCookie`.

Comment: `if (window.location.href != "http://fiddlehead.co/pages/verify-age") {
    var current_url = window.location;
    function createCookie(name, value) {`                                                                     Still not working

Comment: Okay, this appeared to be the main problem. also for some reason I needed to declare the path as '/pages'.  I still don't understand that part of it because I thought declaring the path as '/' made the cookie available to any script on any page.  I'd up your answer but I don't have enough cred yet.  :-)  Thanks for the help!

Comment: And this brings me to an additional question.... if I had written the declaration as `current_url = window.location;` making the variable global, could I have left it inside the body of `createCookie` ?

Comment: @orson Yes, you can have a global variable and use it instead of the `value` parameter. By the way, you can "accept" an answer, not only "upvote" it.